# Validating XML Against a Schema

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am having a problem and i am unable to validate an XML. I have a code where i successfully load XML into a dataset. No problems. If the XML is not according to the schema of the Dataset it throws an exception. The exception thrown is very simple and not useful. Something like "Cannot load XML file ....".

What i am trying to do is to validate the XML before loading into the dataset. I found the following article that does exactly what i want.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/04/02/dataset-does-not-validate-xml-schema-xsd.aspx

When i use the code in the article it gives me the following exception

> Boolean[] is a complex type.Cannot Serialize value of a complex type
>   as Attribute.

One of my columns in the database is boolean[]. Can anybody hint me what is the problem ?

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\abc.xsd");
String test = currentDataset.GetXmlSchema(); //exception
currentDataset.WriteXmlSchema(writer);
```

Edit:

My dataset is defined in an XSD file and i am not generating it from the code. Only 1 table is using a data column with type System.Boolean[] and only this table is not giving exception when i use table.WriteXmlSchema().

Comment: Isn't there a property of the DataColumn type which specifies whether to serialize the column as an attribute vs an element?

Comment: No there isnt apparently

Comment: See the [ColumnMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping.aspx) property.

Comment: Yea i checked that property of the bool[] column and it is already "Element".

Answer (score 0):

Try generating the XSD from the data, as the article does, and comparing that to your `abc.xsd` file.
The following works for me:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable table = ds.Tables.Add("Example");
table.Columns.Add("BoolArray", typeof(bool[]));

table.Rows.Add(new object[] { new bool[]{true, false} });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { new bool[] { false, false } });

StringWriter dataWriter = new StringWriter();
StringWriter schemaWriter = new StringWriter();
table.WriteXmlSchema(schemaWriter);
table.WriteXml(dataWriter, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
Console.WriteLine(schemaWriter.ToString());
```

Comment: I also tried the code in the link that i mentioned. I get an exception at WriteXmlSchema() ... Column System.Boolean[] is a complex type and Cannot Serialize value of a complex type as Attribute.

Comment: When i copied your code. It works fine. Hmmmm where the problem can be ?

Comment: I am able to generate the schema of all the tables except the one with boolean[].

Comment: Possibly it's a difference between the implementations of `GetXmlSchema` and `WriteXmlSchema`?  Try changing to `WriteXmlSchema` and see what you get.

Comment: Based on your edit: the key part is that you're reading the data from a file, rather than creating the columns programmatically.  Have you tried leaving the `bool[]` field out, generating the XSD, then hand-adding that to the XSD afterwards?